# Working with bundler and different platform gem requirements

Tags: ruby, bundler

I seem to struggling with what I thought was standard functionality of bundler, according [the manual](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html)
The ability to specifiy that gems should be required on for certain platforms using the `:platforms` option or `platforms` block

I want to specifcy a different version of a gem dependent on the version of ruby used

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "trollop", "~> 1.16.2"
gem "chronic", "~> 0.6.4"
gem "highline", "~> 1.6.2"
gem "colorize", "~> 0.5.8"
gem "queryparams", "~> 0.0.3"

platforms :ruby_18 do
  gem "json"
  gem "activesupport", "~>2.8.9"
end

platforms :ruby_19 do
  gem "activesupport", "~>3.1.3"
end
```

However this fails when running `bundle install`

```
You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: activesupport (~> 2.8.9) and activesupport (~> 3.1.3)
```

Comment: you can have platform-specific requirements in a Gemfile, please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not doable. A gemfile cannot have the same gem specified with different versions. Not only within different platforms but even not in different groups (group_ruby_18, group_ruby_19) and then by trying 
    bundle install --without group_ruby_18

So this will fail too.

I had this problem before and the only solution I found was to have 2 different GEMFILES.

Comment: Thanks, seems odd, i'd have thought this would be a pretty common requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need 2 different Gemfiles in order to achieve platform-specific gem-requirements.
Just check for the RUBY_VERSION and put your gems in some sort of conditional clause:

```
if(defined?(JRUBY_VERSION))
  gem 'warbler'
else
  case(RUBY_VERSION)
  when('1.8.7')
    gem 'ruby-debug'
  when('1.9.2')
    gem 'ruby-debug19'
  when('1.9.3')
    gem 'debugger'
  end
end
```

That should do the trick.

With best regards,